# summing 1:n elements of a matrix using R without using a for loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to write some code in R to get from this:

```r
    \begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a1 & b1 & c1 & d1 & e1 & f1 & g1 & h1 & i1 & \hdots \\ 
    a2 & b2 & c2 & d2 & e2 & f2 & g2 & h2 & i2 & \hdots \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
```

to this:

```r
    \begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a1 + b1 + c1 & d1 + e1 + f1 & g1 + h1 + i1 & \hdots \\ 
    a2 + b2 + c2 & d2 + e2 + f2 & g2 + h2 + i2 & \hdots \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
```

However not sure if this is possible without using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will juggle it to be right in the end:

```r
## given x

library(magrittr)
smaller.matrix <- matrix( t(x), nrow=3 ) %>%
  colSums %>%
  matrix( byrow=TRUE, nrow=nrow(x) )
```

The `magrittr` library is only there for the `%>%` operator which adds readaiblity. You could go all lisp and wrap the statements into multiple layers of `(...)` if you want to.

Also the above solutions sort requires your column count to be divisible my 3, but that seems like a given based on the description of your problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input in the Note at the end read it into separate lines (omit this if you already have that) and use grep to find the lines to modify and use gsub to perform the modification.

```
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))

hdots <- grep("hdots", L)   
L[hdots] <- gsub("&([^&]*)&([^&]*)&", "+\\1+\\2&", L[hdots])

vdots <- grep("vdots", L)    
L[vdots] <- gsub("(.vdots) & .vdots & .vdots", "\\1", L[vdots])

L <- paste(L, collapse = "\n")

cat(L, "\n")
```

giving:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a1 + b1 + c1 & d1 + e1 + f1 & g1 + h1 + i1 & \hdots \\ 
a2 + b2 + c2 & d2 + e2 + f2 & g2 + h2 + i2 & \hdots \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- r"[
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a1 & b1 & c1 & d1 & e1 & f1 & g1 & h1 & i1 & \hdots \\ 
a2 & b2 & c2 & d2 & e2 & f2 & g2 & h2 & i2 & \hdots \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}]"
```